# php: Multiple prepared statements will not execute

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a PHP script that does several things.

1. Determine if a user is logged in.
2. If no, list some phone numbers
3. If yes, list some phone numbers AND increment the user's version
4. Echo a JSON encoded list

I am using prepared statements.  Everything is fine until I try to increment the user's version.  When I add this statement, nothing will echo, not even the list.  If I remove the update code, the list will echo.  The problem only occurs during POSTs.

Commented below:

```
<?php
include('connections/conn.php');

$userZip = $_GET['zip'];

$uGoogleSecret = $_POST['secret'];

$testsql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM pffusers where uGoogleSecret = ?');
$testsql->bind_param("i",$uGoogleSecret);
$testsql->execute();
$testsql->store_result();

$rarray = array();
if($testsql->num_rows==0){
    $zipSql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM qryzipsphones where zCode = ? and pActive=1;');
    $zipSql->bind_param("s",$userZip);
    $zipSql->execute();
    $zipSql->store_result();
    if($zipSql->num_rows==0){
        $finalZipSql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM qryzipsphones where zCode = 17103 and pActive=1;');
    } else{
        $finalZipSql = $zipSql;
    }
} else{
    $zipSql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM qryzipsphones where zCode = ? and pActive=1;');
    $zipSql->bind_param("s",$userZip);
    $zipSql->execute();
    $zipSql->store_result();
    if($zipSql->num_rows==0){
        $finalZipSql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM qryzipsphones where zCode = 17103 and pActive=1;');
    } else{
        $finalZipSql = $zipSql;
    }
}

$finalZipSql->execute();
$res = $finalZipSql->get_result();
while($finalZip=$res->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($rarray,array(
    'pid'=>$finalZip['pid'],
    'pName'=>$finalZip['pName'],
    'pDisplayNumber'=>$finalZip['pDisplayNumber'],
    'pNumber'=>$finalZip['pNumber'],
    ));
}

$finalZipSql->close();

//Problem begins here
$usql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM pffusers where uGoogleSecret = ?');
$usql->bind_param("i",$uGoogleSecret);
$usql->execute();
$usql->store_result(); 
 if($usql->num_rows==1){
    $urow = $usql->fetch_assoc();
    $uid = $urow['uid'];
    $uversion = $urow['uVersion'];
    $uversion++;
    $uUser = $conn->prepare('update pffusers set uVersion=? where uid=?;');
    $uUser->bind_param("ii",$uversion,$uid);
    $uUser->execute();
}
//Problem ends here

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$rarray));
?>
```

Comment: When you do this `$finalZipSql = $zipSql;` that statement has already been processed and cannot be executed again

Comment: Really now, i never got into [tag:mysqli], but if that's the case I'm glad I started with PDO.

Comment: @SinTek All I can see in this code is that you *fail* at properly handling errors. `bind_param()`, `execute()`, `store_result()` **ALL** return a value if it was successful of doing so. You have an error, yet you don't check for errors see the dilemma you're facing?